# how to create scaffolding for model that is already in place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I have a model already in place.  I just want some admin screens created for it which will do the add/edit/update/delete functionality.

My model name is User and it has properties `user_id, first_name, last_name, user_status, created_at, updated_at, updated_by`

Is it possible to use the `script/generate scaffold` on this model so that crud functionality would come on its own and then I can just make it look like rest of the application.

I dont know if it makes a difference but the `user` model has a `has_many through` relationship with another table

Comment: It's possible! See [**this SO question and answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333393/using-rails-generate-scaffold-when-model-already-exists).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [nifty_scaffold](http://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators) for this

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you simply need an admin controller + views for Users.  You should strongly consider name-spacing the admin area (which is easily possible via the following generator in rails 3):

```
rails generate controller Admin::Users
```

additionally, if you also want the views generated, based on an existing User model:

```
rails generate scaffold_controller Admin::Users
```