# Rails: How to run `rails generate scaffold` when the model already exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails so my current project is in a weird state.

One of the first things I generated was a "Movie" model. I then started defining it in more detail, added a few methods, etc.

I now realize I should have generated it with `rails generate scaffold` to hook up things like the routing, views, controller, etc.

I tried to generate the scaffolding but I got an error saying a migration file with the same name already exists.

What's the best way for me to create scaffolding for my "Movie" now? (using rails 3)

Comment: It's probably best to write your own controllers and views and routes. You'll learn more about the concepts

Comment: Agree with @penne12. At least in the beginning, until you are comfortable with the concepts, so that you know what all the code is doing that is generated for you.

Comment: Not directly relevant but if you ever mess up, use rails destroy <etc>. I remember this was really useful when I started.

Comment: @BenAubin, while true, the beauty of Rails is to not have to continually write boilerplate.

Answer (score 656, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `rails g scaffold_controller <name>`

Even though you already have a model, you can still generate the necessary controller and migration files by using the `rails generate` option. If you run `rails generate -h` you can see all of the options available to you.

```
Rails:
  controller
  generator
  helper
  integration_test
  mailer
  migration
  model
  observer
  performance_test
  plugin
  resource
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  session_migration
  stylesheets
```

If you'd like to generate a controller scaffold for your model, see `scaffold_controller`. Just for clarity, here's the description on that:

> Stubs out a scaffolded controller and its views. Pass the model name,
>       either CamelCased or under_scored, and a list of views as arguments.
>       The controller name is retrieved as a pluralized version of the model
>       name.
>
> To create a controller within a module, specify the model name as a
>       path like 'parent_module/controller_name'.
>
> This generates a controller class in app/controllers and invokes helper,
>       template engine and test framework generators.

To create your resource, you'd use the `resource` generator, and to create a migration, you can also see the `migration` generator (see, there's a pattern to all of this madness). These provide options to create the missing files to build a resource. Alternatively you can just run `rails generate scaffold` with the `--skip` option to skip any files which exist :)

I recommend spending some time looking at  the options inside of the generators. They're something I don't feel are documented extremely well in books and such, but they're very handy.

Comment: wow, one of the best answers i've ever gotten to a programming question. thanks!

Comment: I also have existing models and doing `rails generate scaffold_controller MyModel` does generate the view layer but it doesn't include the model attributes (table columns) and you have to add those by hand.  Anybody know of a fix for this?  I am on Rails 3.2.8.

Comment: @aaronbartell You're asking Rails to generate a 'scaffold_controller' which doesn't care about model attributes. This is not broken, if you want a model generated too then you want `generate scaffold` if you have a model but you want a scaffold controller and new attributes added to a model you want `scaffold_generator` followed by `migration` with the fields you're altering

Comment: @Lee - No aaronbartell is asking how come the scaffold_controller doesn't generate the corresponding view inputs for the existing attributes of the model that was passed to it, which is a valid question... http://stackoverflow.com/q/17153864/165673

Comment: This frankly is not very useful when the majority of the effort of scaffolding is building the view files, and the view files generated by `scaffold_controller` are incomplete.

Answer (score 76):

Great answer by `Lee Jarvis`, this is just the command e.g; we already have an existing model called User:

```
rails g scaffold_controller User
```

Comment: Thank you, for those of us too lazy to read paragraphs of text!

Answer (score 33):

For the ones starting a rails app with existing database there is a cool gem called `schema_to_scaffold` to generate a scaffold script.
it outputs:

> `rails g scaffold users fname:string lname:string bdate:date email:string encrypted_password:string`

from your `schema.rb` our your renamed `schema.rb.` [Check it](https://rubygems.org/gems/schema_to_scaffold)

Comment: This is a great litle gem, it will help me a lot! Should be built-in to Rails!

Answer (score 16):

In **Rails 5**, you can still run

```
$rails generate scaffold movie --skip
```

to create all the missing scaffold files or

```
rails generate scaffold_controller Movie
```

to create the controller and view only.

For a better explanation check out [rails scaffold](https://kolosek.com/rails-scaffold)

Answer (score 12):

This command should do the trick:

```
$ rails g scaffold movie --skip
```

Answer (score 11):

You can make use of `scaffold_controller` and remember to pass the `attributes` of the model, or scaffold will be generated without the attributes.

```
rails g scaffold_controller User name email
# or
rails g scaffold_controller User name:string email:string
```

This command will generate following files:

```
create  app/controllers/users_controller.rb
invoke  haml
create    app/views/users
create    app/views/users/index.html.haml
create    app/views/users/edit.html.haml
create    app/views/users/show.html.haml
create    app/views/users/new.html.haml
create    app/views/users/_form.html.haml
invoke  test_unit
create    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb
invoke  helper
create    app/helpers/users_helper.rb
invoke    test_unit
invoke  jbuilder
create    app/views/users/index.json.jbuilder
create    app/views/users/show.json.jbuilder
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this challenge when working on a **Rails 6** API application in **Ubuntu 20.04**.

I had already existing models, and I needed to generate **corresponding controllers** for the **models** and also add their **allowed attributes** in the **controller params**.

**Here's how I did it**:

I used the `rails generate scaffold_controller` to get it done.

I simply ran the following commands:

```
rails generate scaffold_controller School name:string logo:json motto:text address:text

rails generate scaffold_controller Program name:string logo:json school:references
```

This generated the **corresponding controllers** for the **models** and also added their **allowed attributes** in the **controller params**, including the **foreign key** attributes.

```
create  app/controllers/schools_controller.rb
invoke  test_unit
create    test/controllers/schools_controller_test.rb

create  app/controllers/programs_controller.rb
invoke  test_unit
create    test/controllers/programs_controller_test.rb
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**