# Auto generate scaffolding for an existing database scheme in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, code-generation

I have existing database that I would like to auto generate the controllers and views for including models with field size and not null validation. I looked into a project called the Magic Model Generator but it looked old and only creates models from what I can tell.

I want this as primarily a time saver and I understand that most of the controllers and views will not be useful for user facing functionally. I will be plucking out what I don't need and moving most of it to administration pages.

Is there a tool for doing this?

TIA!

**Edit:** I want to create the actual files and do not want a dynamic admin. I will be using the controllers and view for some front facing parts of the site.

Answer (score 19):

Not sure if works for Rails 3, but does for Rails 4!
Steps below teaches how to build your models, forms, controllers and etc from a existing database.

1. Model and deploy your database, which yet has nothing to do with your rails app.
2. Point your rails app config/database.yml to such database
3. Open terminal
4. Change directory to you rails app root (run in terminal **cd /path/to/my/rails/app/**) .
5. Run in terminal **rake db:schema:dump** (Generates schema.rb)
6. Install gem 'schema_to_scaffold' (https://github.com/frenesim/schema_to_scaffold/)
7. Run in terminal **scaffold** to generate rails scaffold commands and follow what is requested
8. copy "rails scaffold commands" generated by step 7 on a separated .txt file
9. Run each "rails scaffold command" separately
10. Be happy!

Hope it helps!

Comment: This works perfect in Rails 4.0! Thank you for the suggestion, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: On RoR 4.2 is perfect!

Comment: Great! if you have more than 300 tables like me. can you add a `#! /bin/sh` at the first line of the file, add permissions `chmod +x filename` and run it as a script.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this question is answered here:
[How to run `rails generate scaffold` when the model already exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333393/using-rails-generate-scaffold-when-model-already-exists)
and here:
[rails g scaffold for existing model and DB table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808668/rails-g-scaffold-for-existing-model-and-db-table)

with the short answer being (e.g. model = Post)

```
rails generate scaffold_controller Post
```

Comment: I'm looking to generate from an existing database table not a model.

Comment: Why not create a simple model pointing to the database table? rails generate model Post

Comment: And this will create all the views with the forms and fields?

Comment: If you create the model, then run the scaffold_controller command, yes, it will generate all the views with forms and fields.

Comment: I have a `class Stuff < ApplicationRecord; end` in `app/models` but the  command `rails g scaffold_controller Stuff` doesn't generate all the fields in `app/views/stuff/show.html.erb`

Answer (score 3):

RailsAdmin gem
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use this to solve part of your problem. After pointing your rails app to your old database then do a rake db:schema:dump you can use a gem called [schema_to_scaffold](https://rubygems.org/gems/schema_to_scaffold) to generate a scaffold script.
It outputs:

`rails g scaffold users fname:string lname:string bdate:date email:string encrypted_password:string`

from your schema.rb our your renamed schema.rb. Check [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/schema_to_scaffold)