# rails g scaffold for existing model and DB table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, generator, scaffold

I would like to create a structure with
`rails g scaffold Article`, but I have already created the table `Articles` and model `Articles`.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`rails generate scaffold_controller Article`

Comment: A short note: attribute names to be included in the generated views need adding otherwise the views will only contain the stub (at least for Rails 4).

Comment: When run `scaffold_controller` generator script in Rails 4 found some bugs, if i don't make mistake. Generator `scaffold_controller` didn't create routes. It's normal?

Answer (score 2):

Use `rails generate scaffold_controller Article` with parameters, example:

`rails g scaffold_controller Article title:string body:text`

Create views with attributes in tables

Comment: This is the better answer because this is the only one which also includes the data fields you'd like your views to incorporate.