# How do you generate views/controllers/tests given the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do you generate views/controllers/tests for a brand new Rails 3.x application which has all the relevant model classes under app/models.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333393/using-rails-generate-scaffold-when-model-already-exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the console type

```
rails generate controller <controller name> <action1> <action2> <etc..>
```

For instance

```
rails generate controller items new create edit update destroy index show
```

this generates items_controller.rb in app/controllers, new.html.erb, edit.html.erb and other actions in app/views and test templates in test/