# Generate form elements with scaffold_controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

I have already a model in my Ruby on Rails aplication. I want to generate the Controller and Views.

Using the scaffold_controller option i get the files but the forms of the view dosnt contain the html input forms.

I can generate them using the parameters, for example

```
rails g scaffold_controller User name email
```

Is there some way to generate the html input tags without setting them as parameters? Can i make the scaffold_controller  take the data from the existing model?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Actually, when you use `scaffold_controller`, you are telling generator not to consider model.** If you want to consider model attribites, you will need to pass the required attributes, **as you are doing**.

For more clarity:

> Stubs out a scaffolded controller and its views. Pass the model name, either CamelCased or under_scored, and a list of views as arguments. The controller name is retrieved as a pluralized version of the model name.
>
> To create a controller within a module, specify the model name as a
>   path like 'parent_module/controller_name'.
>
> This generates a controller class in app/controllers and invokes
>   helper, template engine and test framework generators.

Another related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333393/using-rails-generate-scaffold-when-model-already-exists)